# Python Creating Dictionary with Multidimension List

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df2), I've converted the dataframe to list which is called "train_list"

You can see the train_list output example below. (Actually this train_list has one million lines.)

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(train_file, sep='\t', header=None)

df2.columns = ["user", "poiid","checkinnumber"]
train_list = df2.values.tolist()

print(train_list)
```

> ```
> [[0, 1, 28],
>      [0, 2, 2],
>      [0, 6, 14],
>      [0, 7, 2],
>      [1, 130, 2],
>      [1, 131, 2],
>      [1, 132, 2],
>      [1, 134, 2],
>      [2, 441, 1],
>      [2, 202, 2],
>      [2, 98, 1],
>      [2, 99, 52],
>      [3, 450, 2],
>      [3, 451, 1],
>      [3, 452, 2],
>      [3, 453, 2]]
> ```

My goal is to create a dictionary like below.

```
0: {1,2,6,7},
1: {130,131,132,134},
2: {441,202,98,99}, ...
```

Here is my solution but I am getting an error,

```
from collections import defaultdict

trainset= defaultdict(set) # creating empty dictionary set

for eachline in train_list :
    uid, lid, _ = eachline.strip().split()
    uid, lid = int(uid), int(lid)
    ground_truth[uid].add(lid)

Error: "'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"
```

Comment: try `df2.groupby('user')['poiid'].agg(set).to_dict()`

Comment: If you type your comment in reply, I will approve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this output using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `set` aggregation and finally, [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df2.groupby('user')['poiid'].agg(set).to_dict()
```

[out]

```
{0: {1, 2, 6, 7},
 1: {130, 131, 132, 134},
 2: {98, 99, 202, 441},
 3: {450, 451, 452, 453}}
```